# To use or ignore positive or negative signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When there is a sequence of positive numbers that ascend, and the calculation is too subtract the greater from the lesser, the result is negative numbers.

There is a set that descends from greater to lesser which graphs as $+x, +y$. the second, the ascending, set graphs as $+ x, - y$. I have been exploring a difficult problem in which I avoided  the Plus or minus by using absolute numbers. but just the other day it occurred to me that I may be losing valuable information about the first set.

Are there rules for when to ignore the plus or minus? I am an amateur in this field, as you can easily surmise, so I need opinions from those with knowledge. I am asking a serious question . 
Are there times when one loses useful information by ignoring the signs? Of course that information would be about the first set, not about the second. Then why or why not? thank you

Comment: It *heavily* depends on the context. A lot of times a sign doesn't matter, since we only care about the magnitude or absolute value. Other times it does because it codifies *orientation*, an important property of certain objects (for example). I obviously can't tell which is the case with your numbers though.

Comment: Thank  you. context does mean that I should use the negative signs in the second set.. The contacts is B contrast between A to the nth power and 1 - a^n

Comment: An example: (1-9^3)=.271, then for the 8 & 7: .488, .657. The calculation is .271-.488= -271. And .488 - .657 = -.169.  The next step would be subtract - 169 from -271 = - .48. -48 is relevan because n equal 3 divides the -48. This is an example for all n these steps leads to n dividing the last rational number. I AM asserting the abstract generalization without telling the whole story so do not expect to C my general..point. I just hope you can follow the subtractions

Comment: I can follow a little bit. However it seems a more experienced person would have to tell you when a sequence of additions/subtractions would be divisible by the same number, after altering some signs. I do not know this.

Comment: G P, thank you, it is good the way you say that, you follow some, and acknowledge you do not have the expertise to say more. The issue is a complex one. The expert said that the signs may indicate orientation. The +x, -y is in the 4th quadrant and has the same shape but is a reflection of the shape in the 1st quadrant.  The procedure I use always subtracts the second number from first.

Comment: In 1 of his few proofs Fermat demonstrated that 2^n-2, for prime n, n always divides the result. Consider 2, 1, 0 for n=3. The expansion is to 8, 1, 0. 8-1=7; 1-0=1. The second subtractions: 7-1=6. Fermat's (-2) is here as the 1st (-1) and the 2nd (-1). Using 3 and 4 the same procedure gives 27 and 64. 64-27=19; the second subtraction gives 18. 3|18. My observation for many examples is that n always divides the relevant subtractions.

Comment: Oops, sorry G Perez, you are the expert who told me about orientation. I now see that you followed some of my example thank you

Comment: I didn't mean to say that in your case it indicates orientation. I just gave an example of a sign mattering (and I'm certainly not an expert!).

Comment: I understood. that orientation it is related to the negative number then I se to myself I should use the negative because look reconstruction that I use thank you

Comment: Typos. I concluded myself that I will use the negative because the construction that use calls for that.

Comment: Typo in Fermat's 2^n-2, ... using 3 & 4: 64-27=37; then 27-8=19, then 19-7=12. 3|12.